# Bash, error storing a directory name in a variable

Tags: bash

I know this is probably a silly question, but I am trying to write my first bash script and am having some trouble. It is a backup script that reads a text file to get a list of directories to back up, then stores them in a variable so it can use the variable value as input for the tar command. But when if I store the value /home in the backupdirs text file, it gives me an error saying /home is a directory, and it does not store it in the variable. Can I not store a directory name in a variable like this? How do I get around it?

```
#!/bin/bash

BACKUP_DIRS=

cat /root/backupdirs.txt |
{
        while read line
        do
            echo $line
            BACKUP_DIRS=$BACKUP_DIRS $line
        done
}

echo $INPUT_DIRS

/bin/tar -czf backup $BACKUP_DIRS
```

Comment: What do you think the line `BACKUP_DIRS=$BACKUP_DIRS $line` is doing? I'd bet that it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Also, does your `tar` support the `-T` option? very likely your problem can be solved altogether with this single line: `tar -T /root/backupdirs.txt -czf backup.tar.gz`.

Comment: I thought that line was taking the value of BACKUP_DIRS plus one space and then the value of line, and then assigning this to BACKUP_DIRS. No?

Comment: No, you need quotes for this to happen: `BACKUP_DIRS="$BACKUP_DIRS $line"`. What your line does is try to execute what `$line` expands to, with environmental variable `BACKUP_DIRS` set to the expansion of `$BACKUP_DIRS`.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I see how it works now. Also, it turns out my tar does have the -T option, so I rewrote the script to use that. Thanks to you and the answer below, I can now do this multiple ways. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you use the pipe, it creates a subshell. Then `BACKUP_DIRS` is saved in the subshell. Once the subshell exits, the variable is destroyed along with it. One way around this, do it without a pipe

```
while read line
do
  echo $line
  BACKUP_DIRS+=" $line"
done </root/backupdirs.txt
```